# sed command to edit a file at multiple conditions

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have file which have multiple rows of columns which need to be handled as per requirement. I found a script that does this with variables, but I don't want do this with variables as this makes my code more complex

file:

```
Id,Name,class,Section
1,Dileep,MBA,B
2,Pavan,tenth,C
3,Girish,graduate,D
```

My output file should be like this -

file:

```
Id,Name,Class,Section
1,Dileep,MBA,B
2,Pavan,MCA,C
3,Girish,MBA,D
```

I have used sed command to do this and below is the script I created for this.

```
#! /bin/sh
file=/tmp/dileep/details.txt

cat $file | sed '/Id,Name,/s/class/**C**lass/g' | tee -a $file 
cat $file | sed '/2,Pavan,/s/tenth/**MCA**/g' | tee -a $file
cat $file | sed '/3,Girish,/s/graduate/**MBA**/g' | tee -a $file
```

I am able to get the first line changed the one with header, but not the actual data, this is going to be hard-coded data and I can make this change.

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can get this corrected.

Comment: You can't use `tee` like this. As soon as the input file is larger than the buffer size used by `tee` you loose your input file.

Comment: do you only want to replace `tenth` by `MCA` when the line starts with `2,Pavan`? Or why do you do `/2,Pavan,/s/tenth/**MCA**/g` and not just `s/tenth/**MCA**/g`?

Comment: I would like to check for the condition if 2,Pavan then change it to MCA if Class is tenth, similarly for the others, I need to validate if the required content is found then I need to change it to the desired value

Comment: Did you get a good answer?

Comment: No Walter A, I just took the tee -a and am trying to see if it is going to break at some point

Answer (score 1):

**First(!)**

You can't use tee like this. As soon as the input file is larger than the buffer size used by tee you will **loose** your input file.

---

About the topic, do you mean something like this?

I would use `awk`:

*sanitize.awk*:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}

$3=="class" {
    $3="Class"
}

$3=="tenth"{
    $3="MCA"
}

$3=="graduate" {
    $3="MBA"
}

{
    print
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f sanitize.awk input.file > output.file
mv output.file > input.file
```

Comment: refer my answer, improvised a bit to use the actual conditions used in OP. will be happy to remove if you can add those conditions.

Comment: I have the feeling that those checks are what the OP does *not* want. Otherwise the question makes no sense for me.

Comment: Yeah even I was not sure. But his intention with `sed` prompted me to provide such a logic.

Comment: I am a starter with sed command and don't have knowledge about awk, I am not aware of what OP means in your comments. Can you please elaborate

Comment: You are the OP (*Original Poster*). What we wanted to say is that your requirements are unclear. Does this work for you?

Comment: my requirement is check if the line has 'Id,Name,class,' then in that line change 'class' to 'Class' with C in CAPS, similarly for other conditions, check if the content exists then change it over. Hope this helps, pls let me know if you are still unclear

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed in different ways. I will first fix your script

```
file=/tmp/dileep/details.txt
output=/tmp/dileep/details.out
# Off-topic: cat $file | sed '...' can be replaced by sed '...' $file
cat $file | sed '/Id,Name,/s/class/**C**lass/g' |
            sed '/2,Pavan,/s/tenth/**MCA**/g' |
            sed '/3,Girish,/s/graduate/**MBA**/g' | tee -a ${output}
```

With sed you can use the option `-e`:

```
file=/tmp/dileep/details.txt
output=/tmp/dileep/details.out
# No spaces after the last '\' of the line!
cat $file | sed -e '/Id,Name,/s/class/**C**lass/g' \
                -e '/2,Pavan,/s/tenth/**MCA**/g' \
                -e '/3,Girish,/s/graduate/**MBA**/g' | tee -a ${output}
```

Or you can use 1 long command (looks terrible):

```
cat $file | sed -e \
  '/Id,Name,/s/class/**C**lass/g;/2,Pavan,/s/tenth/**MCA**/g;/3,Girish,/s/graduate/**MBA**/g' | tee -a ${output}
```

What you need here is a commandfile:

```
cat /tmp/dileep/commands.sed
/Id,Name,/s/class/**C**lass/g
/2,Pavan,/s/tenth/**MCA**/g
/3,Girish,/s/graduate/**MBA**/g
```

And use

```
cat $file | sed -f /tmp/dileep/commands.sed | tee -a ${output}
```

or better, avoiding the `cat`

```
sed -f /tmp/dileep/commands.sed ${file} | tee -a ${output}
```